# I am able to run python on my command prompt of windows but unable to run it in terminal of atom editor

Tags: python, atom-editor

[When I tried to use python command in my terminal of atom it shows such error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LheIW.jpg)
And when same thing I tried through command promt it works. plzz help me out.

Comment: It looks like you need to add python to the system PATH

Comment: @roganjosh yes after setting system path It works thanks for guidance

Comment: Images of text are not accessible, nor are they searchable, and they are hard to read on smaller size screens. You can [edit] your question to paste in code and error messages and format them accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this your Python directory? i.e. is there a file called 'python.exe' in there?

As far as I know, atom should inherit the PATH variables from the command prompt (I may be mistaken). If you restart atom, does this persist?

And also - when you tested it with command prompt, was it pointing to the same directory? Essentially, it's not opening because it needs to either 
a) see a Python executable in the current directory, or
b) know where to find the Python executable (PATH variable)

Adding python to PATH:
https://superuser.com/questions/143119/how-do-i-add-python-to-the-windows-path

Comment: Yes I have used same directory in my command prompt too.
And I also restarted my atom but issue persist.